# Playing video in android directly from server

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming

I am currently playing a video in andriod from the url http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp
its working successfully.

But here i need to play that url through server, please let me know how to play.

Find the code below:

**CODE**

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity {
private VideoView videoView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView_surface_1);

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp"));


    videoView.requestFocus();}}
```

Thanks for your Time!!

Comment: can you please explain playing url from server means ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `videoview.start()` after this call only videoview will start playing video.